# Entering variables into regression function

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, nls

I have this feature_list that contains several possible values, say "A", "B", "C" etc. And there is time in time_list.

So I will have a loop where I will want to go through each of these different values and put it in a formula.

something like `for(i in ...)` and then `my_feature <- feature_list[i]` and `my_time <- time_list[i]`.

Then I put the time and the chosen feature to a dataframe to be used for regression

```
feature_list<- c("GPRS")
time_list<-c("time")
calc<-0

feature_dim <- length(feature_list)
time_dim <- length(time_list)

data <- read.csv("data.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
result <- matrix(nrow=0, ncol=5)
errors<-matrix(nrow=0, ncol=3)

for(i in 1:feature_dim) {
    my_feature <- feature_list[i]
    my_time <- time_list[i]

    fitdata <- data.frame(data[my_feature], data[my_time])

    for(j in 1:60) {

        my_b <- 0.0001 * (2^j)

        for(k in 1:60) {
            my_c <- 0.0001 * (2^k)
            cat("Feature: ", my_feature, "\t")
            cat("b: ", my_b, "\t")
            cat("c: ", my_c, "\n")

            err <- try(nlsfit <- nls(GPRS ~ 53E5*exp(-1*b*exp(-1*c*time)), data=fitdata, start=list(b=my_b, c=my_c)), silent=TRUE)
            calc<-calc+1

            if(class(err) == "try-error") {
                next
            }

            else {
                coefs<-coef(nlsfit)
                ess<-deviance(nlsfit)
                result<-rbind(result, c(coefs[1], coefs[2], ess, my_b, my_c))
            }
    }
} 
}
```

Now in the `nls()` call I want to be able to call my_feature instead of just "A" or "B" or something and then to the next one on the list. But I get an error there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1. It be helpful if you tell what error you get (maybe copy-paste error message?)
2. There is misspell in your code: `data` and `start` argument aren't passed to `nls` (brace is close too soon)

Comment: yeah the code isn't exact as I was just illustrating the problem. Which is that, I cannot use the my_feature variable inside the nls call but can only have put "A" in the formula.

Comment: i have put the exact formula now

Comment: What is the structure of your list? If it's a named list, it is easily converted to a data frame, allowing you to use A etc. The data() command  in the data.frame looks very strange to me, as that one is used to call builtin datasets. Some runnable sample code and data would be very useful, this way it is impossible to say where the problem is, or even what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: @Joris the actual code is there now, i thought just giving the problem statement wud be alrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use paste to create a string version of your formula including the variable name you want, then use either `as.formula` or `formula` functions to convert this to a formula to pass to nls.

```
as.formula(paste(my_feature, "~ 53E5*exp(-1*b*exp(-1*c*time))"))
```

Another option is to use the bquote function to insert the variable names into a function call, then eval the function call.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with R a while ago, maybe you can give this a try:

What you want is create a formula with a list of variables right?

so if the response variable is the first element of your list and the others are the explanatory variables you could create your formula this way:

my_feature[0] ~ reduce("+",my_feature[1:]) .  This might work.

this way you can create formulae that depends on the variables in my_features.

Comment: the function is spelled with a capital (Reduce), very important in R. Next to that, Reduce() **applies** the function "+", so you can't use it to build a formula. You either get the sume of my_feature[1:] or the notice that you try to apply a non-numeric argument to a binary operator.